# Add extra pair of UL using JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have done coding the first part HTML then JavaScript/JQuery. Now I want to surround the final common list with a UL need to be done using JavaScript/JQuery. So the final common list will be surrounded by two UL instead of one. Eg
**Final Outcome**

```
<ul id="CommonLister">
       <ul> <!--Need to add this-->
         <li class="columnItem">John</li>
         <li class="columnItem">Mark</li>
       </ul><!--Need to add this-->
</ul>
```

Current Code

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <div>
              <ul id="listOne">
                <li class="columnItem">John</li><!--will be removed and put under CommonLister-->
                <li class="columnItem">James</li>
                <li class="columnItem">Mary</li><!--will be removed and put under CommonLister-->
              </ul>

          <ul id="listTwo">
            <li class="columnItem">John</li><!--will be removed and put under CommonLister-->
            <li class="columnItem">Mark</li>
            <li class="columnItem">Mary</li><!--will be removed and put under CommonLister-->
          </ul>
          <ul id="CommonLister">
            <li class="columnItem">John</li>
            <li class="columnItem">Mark</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

    $(function() {
      $('#run-code').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //What were you doing? nope.
        var currentItems = {}; //Blank object
        var $mergeColumn = $('#CommonLister'); //Common list reference
        $('.columnItem').each(function(i, el) {
          var $el = $(el); //Notation I use to differentiate between the regular HTML Element and jQuery element
          if (!currentItems.hasOwnProperty($el.html())) {
            //Has this name come up before? if not, create it.
            currentItems[$el.html()] = []; //Make it equal to a brand spanking new array
          }
          currentItems[$el.html()].push(el);
          //Add the item to the array
        });

        $.each(currentItems, function(name, data) {
          //Loop through each name. We don't actually use the name variable because we don't care what someone's name is
          if (data.length > 1) {
            //Do we have more than 1 element in our array? time to move some stuff
            $.each(data, function(i, el) {
              var $el = $(el); //See note above
              if (i == 0) {
                //If this is the first element, let's just go ahead and move it to the merge column ul
                $el.appendTo($mergeColumn);
              } else {
                $el.remove(); //Otherwise, we've already got this element so delete this one.
              } //end if/else
            }); //end $.each(data)
          } //end if data.length >1
        }); //end $.each(currentItems)

      }); //end $.on()
    }); //end $(

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button id="run-code" class="btn btn-success">Click Me</button>

    <h4>List 1</h4>
    <ul id="listOne">
      <li class="columnItem">John</li>
      <!--will be removed and put under CommonLister-->
      <li class="columnItem">James</li>
      <li class="columnItem">Mary</li>
      <!--will be removed and put under CommonLister-->
    </ul>
    <h4>List 2</h4>
    <ul id="listTwo">
      <li class="columnItem">John</li>
      <!--will be removed and put under CommonLister-->
      <li class="columnItem">Mark</li>
      <li class="columnItem">Mary</li>
      <!--will be removed and put under CommonLister-->
    </ul>
    <h4>Common List</h4>
    <ul id="CommonLister"> 
    <!--Extra ul will be added here-->
    </ul>
```

Comment: `<ul>` can not be a direct child of another `<ul>` so not really clear why you are trying to do this. Also not clear why `Mary` isn't included

Comment: I am using this JQuery Tree that follows following notation.

Comment: No...it can't, it is invalid html

Comment: Change the CommonLister to a div and voila it's valid

Answer (score 1):

It's invalid nesting a `ul` directly in a `ul` like this but if you have to, you could use jquery wrapAll:

```
$( "li" ).wrapAll( "<ul></ul>" );
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9xLt6d9f/

Comment: life saver/job saver

Comment: life saver/job saver. It's actually valid the code is so long I had to shortened it down its a <ul><li><ul><li></ul></li></ul></li>.  I am cloning this code under another div. Thanks for your help(fellow Countryman).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with charlietfl that it seems strange to do it this way.  However, to answer your question, the best way to force this improperly formatted HTML code would be hardcode it into your original file.  Try the following code for the end of your file:

```
<h4>Common List</h4>
<ul id="CommonLister">
  <ul id="CommonListerSub"> 
<!--Extra ul will be added here-->
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Then, simply change one line of your code:

```
var $mergeColumn = $('#CommonListerSub'); //Common list reference
```

This will force it to list the list items under the nested `ul` tags.

I hope this is an acceptable solution.  If for some reason it doesn't work, please comment as to what additional limitations you have, and perhaps share the link of the page that is giving you the required template or format specifications.